# Switching Collections using python script

Tags: python, database, mongodb, shell, collections

I am currently writing a data migration script and am calling the following line within a function in the script:

```
output_file.write(process_input_row(row, custom_field_map, args.entry_type, args.entry_prefix, args.book_name))
```

within the call to process_input_row, I have am inserting data into the current collection it is targeting by default. what I want to do is call the standard "use Collection_Name" that you would usually call from the mongo shell from the python script so it inserts the data into the correct collection.

What would be the easiest way of doing this? Could I add "from subprocess import call" to the top of my file and do something like "call('use Collection_Name')" ?
See below:

```
with open(args.entries_file, newline='') as csv_input_file, open(args.output_file, 'w') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_input_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    row_counter = 0
    max_id = 0
    for row in reader:
        if int(row[1]) > max_id:
            max_id = int(row[0])
        output_file.write(process_input_row(row, custom_field_map, args.entry_type, args.entry_prefix, args.book_name))
        row_counter = row_counter + 1
    max_id += 1

    # Switch to different collection here
    call('use Collection_Name')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you writing to an external file? It seems to me that you're opening a CSV file, then for each row you're writing to a file based on the output of `process_input_row()`. If your goal is to insert into MongoDB, why not use Pymongo to insert the row to the database directly in this line?

Comment: I am building off of an existing script and this is how they want it done. It's a data migration script that is taking data from a MySQL database, writing fields to a csv, and importing via csv to a mongoDB.

Comment: All I need to know is how to call a command that you would normally call in the mongo shell from a python script

Comment: I'm assuming you're using pymongo? There is no 1-1 mapping between pymongo and the mongo shell, so there's no direct way to do `use xxx`. You can however specify the database name from the connection object, see http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html. So the script you posted above processes the CSV then writes to an output file, and you import that file into MongoDB?